# Unifying receiver not working for keyboard but for mice

Tags: usb, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I don't know if this is the right site for this post, but my problem is that the wireless logitech k&m receiver broke and I bought a new logitech unifying receiver. This new logitech receiver connector is able to pair with the mouse but not with the keyboard. Is this because the keyboard doesn't have an on-off switch like the mouse?

Kindly provide me a solution as both the k&m were working fine and in perfect condition. I can buy a new set but why not try to mend when there is a chance!

Comment: Have you reviewed the keyboard's manual from Logitech's site?

Answer (score 0):

Add your keyboard back with the [Software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-au/articles/360025297913-Unifying-Software)